# How to get client or local IP from IdTCPClient?

Tags: sockets, delphi, indy

After connect the remote server, how can I get which address the tcp client is using?

I want to connect a remote server (eg: 8.8.8.8), and don't want to set `BoundIP`, I just want to know which local IP the `IdTCPClient` is using.

Comment: @TLama Have updated the question. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @JerryDodge If I don't set it, it's an empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once connected, you can get the locally bound IP (regardless of how it was bound, implicitly or explicitly) from the `TIdTCPClient.Socket.Binding.IP` property.

Comment: Thank you. I have searched on Google for hours, you saved me.